# I double clicked a .vcf file - now I can't shut all the windows

Tags: windows-7

I made the mistake of double clicking a large .vcf file. It produced a window showing the properties of the first contact in the address book, which I then shut down by clicking on the little X in the top right of the window - but as soon as I did that, I was presented with a new window showing the properties of the second contact in the address book... and so on and so on...this could take hours! Is there a way to close all of the windows in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this might be to utilize the Task Manager and kill the process. Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Esc` to open Task Manager, and go to Processes. Find the `wab.exe` process and end it.

And of course you could try restarting your Windows system.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I had no idea it was wab.exe that I needed to kill. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! Infinite pop-up windows are no fun...